# Selecting specific time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a column that called `created` that is a mysql timestamp. I have to select records that are created between the previous day's 5 PM to the present day's 4:59 PM.

Supposing I pass in the date as 25-8-2014 to the program, it should fetch me all the records created between 24 -8- 2014 5:00 PM to 25-8-2014 4:49 PM. How do we write a query to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where created between 
curdate() - interval 1 day + interval 17 hour 
and
curdate() + interval 16 hour + interval 59 minute;
```

or

```
select * from your_table
where created between 
date_format(now() - interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d 17:00:00')
and
date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d 16:59:00');
```

or

```
select * from your_table
where created between 
concat(curdate() - interval 1 day, ' 17:00:00') /*note the whitespace before 17*/
and
concat(curdate(), ' 16:59:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` clause. The `BETWEEN` operator selects values within a range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

**Example:**

```
Select *  from  tableNawhere created between date1 and date2;
```

**Note:** In your case, `date1` should be `(date2 - 1day)`

Comment: Wrong, if date2 = date1 - 1 day, it will fetch 0 records. Also note, that between is inclusive. And I doubt, that the OP wants to insert the dates manually each time he executes the query.